# Can we use "Drop-down" instead of "Column Groups" in Tabulator

Tags: html, tabulator

I would like to replace "Column Groups" in tabulator with Drop-down, please let me know if it is possible.

Eg: the screen-shot [Sample Column Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4reWz.png)  shows "Progress" "Rating" "Driver" under Column Group, but I would like to replace those headers with "drop-down" and make "Progress" as Default.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Ramesh-Cisco, please share what you tried so we can help and read this guide about how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Will the header menu options available here:
```http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/menu#header-menu```
help?